# Is it possible to change PieRenderer programatically?

Tags: java, android, androidplot

I'd like to create a pie chart, with segment labels rendered on two lines.

To do that, I have to override `PieRenderer.drawSegmentLabel` ([source on bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/androidplot/androidplot/src/d90fc9fe7705a3f82fe44406cd28a34d9169e056/AndroidPlot-Core/src/main/java/com/androidplot/pie/PieRenderer.java?at=master#cl-174)), but I don't know, how to set my renderer class to the `PieChart` object.

I found a `pie.getRenderer(PieRenderer.class)`, to get the renderer, but I'm not found any method set it. Is there any way to set my renderer to the `PieChart`? I don't want to work with the AndroidPlot's source.

(Androidplot version: 0.6.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually the Formatter that tells Androidplot which Renderer to use when drawing; when you add a segment / series, you always pass in an instance of a Formatter along with it.  You'll need to extend SegmentFormatter like this:

```
/**
 * Formatter used by MyPieRenderer to draw a segment.
 */
class MySegmentFormatter extends SegmentFormatter {

    @Override
    public Class<? extends SeriesRenderer> getRendererClass() {
        return MyPieRenderer.class;
    } 

    @Override
    public SeriesRenderer getRendererInstance(final PieChart plot) {
        return new MyPieRenderer(plot);
    }       
}
```

You can/should also add any other formatting params into this class to be used by your drawSegmentLabel implementation.

Finally, make sure you use an instance of MySegmentFormatter when add the segments that you want rendered by MyPieRenderer:

```
pie.addSeries(series, new MySegmentFormatter());
```

Comment: Your answer is almost full, but let me extend your answer. Without extending the `getRendererInstance`, the plot is not rendered for me. (see: https://bitbucket.org/androidplot/androidplot/src/f4130df7b4f43c8f9b7834b4c9fd73422998ed3f/AndroidPlot-Core/src/main/java/com/androidplot/pie/SegmentFormatter.java?at=0.6.1#cl-128)

Comment: Oops - you're absolutely right!  Can't believe I left that out.  Not sure why your edit got denied by those reviewers but I'll update my answer with the correction :)